# How do you report a defect to Skype for Business?

Tags: skype, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper, defects, videocall

I'd like to report a bug to Skype for Business. I noticed there is a get logs button on Skype but no way to actually report a problem. What can I do to report what I'm seeing and send over the logs file so that a Skype for Business developer could look at it?

Comment: Please consider what questions to ask on Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

Skype => Help => Give Feedback
You can report it here or by using the feedback option in the Skype client.
Try it